# Get thumbnail from Vimeo object

Tags: php, symfony, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using symfony2 with Prismic.

I am passing the vimeo object from the template to a controller, to extraxt the thumb and pass it back to the template.

Template:

```
{{ render(controller('PrismicBundle:Default:getVimThumb', { 'obj' : vimObj })) }}
```

Controller:

```
public function getVimThumbAction($obj) {

var_dump($obj);die;

}
```

Which outputs an object:

```
object(Prismic\Fragment\StructuredText)#861 (1) { ["blocks":"Prismic\Fragment\StructuredText":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Prismic\Fragment\Block\EmbedBlock)#859 (1) { ["obj":"Prismic\Fragment\Block\EmbedBlock":private]=> object(Prismic\Fragment\Embed)#858 (7) { ["type":"Prismic\Fragment\Embed":private]=> string(5) "video" ["provider":"Prismic\Fragment\Embed":private]=> string(5) "Vimeo" ["url":"Prismic\Fragment\Embed":private]=> string(26) "https://vimeo.com/99787515" ["maybeWidth":"Prismic\Fragment\Embed":private]=> int(640) ["maybeHeight":"Prismic\Fragment\Embed":private]=> int(360)

...

["title"]=> string(9) "AiOP FREE" ["author_name"]=> string(11) "Carey Estes" ["author_url"]=> string(29) "http://vimeo.com/user13023202" ["is_plus"]=> string(1) "0" ["html"]=> string(173) "" ["width"]=> int(640) ["height"]=> int(360) ["duration"]=> int(39) ["description"]=> string(35) "Art in Odd Places: FREE Promo video"

...
```

**The important part...**

```
["thumbnail_url"]=> string(45) "http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/481085850_640.jpg" ["thumbnail_width"]=> int(640) ["thumbnail_height"]=> int(360) ["video_id"]=> int(99787515) ["embed_url"]=> string(26) "https://vimeo.com/99787515" } } } } }
```

The thumbnail url and id are in the object. I just don't know how to extract it.

I have worked with the API, which pulls the thumb from the ID, which I could do, if I could extract the ID, however, that seems like overkill since the thumb url is in the object too. How do I pull that from the object?

It's an object so

`$obj["whatever key"]` doesn't work

I have not written a method which I could do, but I still wouldn't know what to write in the method.

Is there a better/another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

PHP Object's use arrows to reference properties.

Try $obj->thumbnail_url

Comment: Thanks Dashron. Tried that. Returns this exception: ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined property: Prismic\Fragment\StructuredText::$thumbnail_url in /Sites/macp-prismic/src/VAP/Bundle/PrismicBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 289. Is this an issue with a Private Property, rather than public?

Comment: No, that makes it seem like thubmnail_url doesn't even exist. Unfortunately I'm not terribly familiar with Prismatic, maybe their devs have a better idea?